# How to "pack" some strings in a list on Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to write a function pack such that

```
pack ['a','a','a','b','c','c','a','a','d','e','e','e'] 
= ["aaa","b","cc","aa","d","eee"]
```

How can I do this? I'm stuck...

Comment: If you're working on "textbook" problems, then it's good to become familiar with [99 Haskell problems](https://wiki.haskell.org/H-99:_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems).  This is problem 9, and the solutions page shows [several ways to do it](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/Solutions/9) (as it does for each).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Data.List.group`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group):

```
λ> import Data.List (group)
λ> :t group
group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
λ> group ['a','a','a','b','c','c','a','a','d','e','e','e']
["aaa","b","cc","aa","d","eee"]
```

Unless you want to write the function yourself (see [Michael Foukarakis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37297681/5559663))

Answer (score 1):

Here's something off the top of my head:

```
pack :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
pack [] = []
-- We split elements of a list recursively into those which are equal to the first one,
-- and those that are not. Then do the same for the latter:
pack (x:xs) = let (first, rest) = span (==x) xs
              in (x:first) : pack rest
```

[Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#group) already has what you're looking for, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth adding a more explicit/beginner version:

```
pack :: [Char] -> [String]
pack [] = []
pack (c:cs) =
    let (v, s) = findConsecutive [c] cs
    in v : pack s
  where
    findConsecutive ds [] = (ds, [])
    findConsecutive s@(d:ds) t@(e:es)
        | d /= e = (s, t)
        | otherwise = findConsecutive (e:s) es
```

If the input is an empty list, the outcome is also an empty list. Otherwise, we find the next consecutive `Char`s that are equal and group them together into a `String`, which is returned in the result list. In order to do that we use the  `findConsecutive` auxiliary function. This function's behavior resembles the [`takeWhile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile) function, with the difference that we know in advance the predicate to use (equality comparison) and that we return both the consumed and the remaining list.

In other words, the signature of `findConsecutive` could be written as:

```
findConsecutive :: String -> [Char] -> (String, String)
```

which means that it takes a string containing only repeated characters to be used as an accumulator and a list whose characters are "extracted" from. It returns a tuple containing the current sequence of elements and the remaining list. Its body should be intuitive to follow: while the characters list is not empty and the current element is equal to the ones in the accumulator, we add the character to the accumulator and recursive into the function. The function returns when we reach the end of the list or a different character is encountered.

The same rationale can be used to understand the body of `pack`.